# How to get "Peak.ar" to work on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini

Tags: sensors, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, calibration

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini and try to get [Peak.ar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.srfg.peakar) working correctly. However, it seems to me that none of the involved sensors (gyro, accelerometer and compass I guess?) is sensitive enough to make it behave reasonably. Besides the fact that the peaks are typically already initially shown with quite (!) some offset in both elevation and azimuth (rather: x and y), also when I move the phone it does not move accordingly, lags behind and eventually gets an even larger offset (or smaller - I sometimes use it to reduce the initial error).
I already tried to calibrate the sensors by this magic command `*#0*#` , but this changed absolutely nothing.

Does anybody have an idea how to improve the behavior? (with particular focus on the Peak.ar app)